# Как урезать текст из базы содержащий ббкоды

Tags: php

В базе текст храниться в виде bbcode

Когда необходимо вывести только часть текста для превью (допустим первые 500 символов) как избавиться от лишнего бб кода?

Да и вообще как вы решали такую проблему

стоит учитывать что бб коды могут быть вложенными

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, я бы написал парсер BBCode. (Собственно, у меня такой где-то уже есть.)

Дальше просто: вы идёте по распознанному синтаксическому дереву, и считаете символы в чистом тексте. Как только количество символов перевалит за 500, мы нашли точку окончания.

Теперь вам надо сериализовать ваше синтаксическое дерево назад в BBCode-текст. Дойдя до точки окончания, просто закройте все незакрытые теги, и всё. Возможно, надо будет сериализовать назад не в BBCode, а прямо в HTML (или что у вас там используется для вывода).